# Properties of a Burning Candle

Tags: thermodynamics

I was just having a discussion with some friends about candles, and I came up with a good question: do candles burn at a constant rate?

I would assume that the answer is no, as the bigger the candle, the more mass there is for the heat to distribute over. I know that it should burn at an approximately constant rate, as that is what people used to use as a timer back in the old days.

I don't know how to even start with this problem, so does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you should fix your question to be more clear. "does a single candle burn at a constant rate" sounds like you are asking if a candle will burn faster or slower after it is lit. 
switch to: "do candles of different girths have their lengths melt at different speeds?"

Comment: Consider the extreme case of some mega candle. You need the wick to also be scaling in size, else there will be parts of the candle that dont /ever/ melt.

Comment: I understand that candles of different "girths" melt at different rates, up to an extent. However, I am more curious if given a single candle if the rate at which the candle melts changes as it burns more and more.

Comment: Are you aware of [candle clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_clock)?

Comment: I am! But I'm curious how accurate they are.

Comment: Assuming a skinny enough candle that the burning does not create a crater that continually deepens (e.g., skinnier than some pillar candles.) And, assuming that the material from which the candle is made has uniform properties throughout. And, assuming that the wick is centered and the candle thickness does not vary with height. And, assuming a steady supply of fresh air, but _calm_ fresh air. And, assuming that enough time has passed for the candle to achieve a steady-state condition... Then probably yes. The burn rate probably will "close enough" to constant for _some_ practical purpose.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, you see, I'm kinda curious about all the extra details. I guess I am willing to give uniformity, the wick being centered, the thickness is not varying, it's a perfect right cylinder, and that there is steady and calm fresh air. However, I think I might be curious in non-steady state, and am for sure curious in a thicker candle.